# Error when adding values to an Access ADP form bound to a SQL stored procedure with a join

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2008r2-express, adp

I have an Access 2003 ADP project that connects to SQL Server 2008 Express Edition.

When I try adding values to a form that has as it's RecordSource a SQL Strored Procedure that uses a JOIN, I get the following error:

You can't update the record because another user or application deleted it or changed the value of its primary key.

The code for the Stored Procedure is:

```
SELECT F.Description, T.Quantity, T.Points
FROM Test T
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblCriteriaCategory1 F 
ON T.FunctionalityID = F.tblCriteriaCategory1ID
```

(The values I'm trying to add are those for Quantity and Points to table Test)

I have also created the appropriate ForeignKey relationship on the Test and tblCriteriaCategory1 tables.

Thank you for any assistace with the above

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to make FunctionalityID the primary key for Test.

This [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295250) show almost the exact same scenario as you are experiencing

Comment: Hi CodeSlave, thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention that I did see the knowledge base article you mentioned and followed those instructions originally but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Edit your question with that info and you'll have a better chance of getting an answer to your question.